# Getting a null array when getting permissions in my app

Tags: android, arrays, android-permissions

I just added to my app Report A bug, and I wanted to save permissions.

When I put code to get all permissions in array (`info.permissions`(`PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);`)) and when I get each permission

```
for (PermissionInfo perm_info : info.permissions) {
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append("Permission Name:");
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append(perm_info.name);
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append("Group: ");
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append(perm_info.group);
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append("Protection Level: ");
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append(perm_info.protectionLevel);
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                    errorReport.append("\n");
                }
```

Problem was not in errorReport String Builder, it works fine, but array is null.

I put this, to confirm, that problem was not in PackageInfo:

```
PackageInfo info = null;
        try {
            info = manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("DeviceReport", e.toString());
        }
```

And I am not getting any errors from DeviceReport.

Why am I getting Null array?

Or if this method of getting permissions will no longer work, what I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer after few hours. Problem was that, I don't have permissions with tag `<permissions>` and I will get permissions with tag `<uses-permission>` by `info.requestedPermissions`.